# The current Dart SDK version does not satisfy null-safety dependences

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm upgrading my project into sound null-safety. After changing the version to

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

then done converting my source code into null-safety syntax.
When I ran my project, it ran `flutter pub get`, and the problem happened

```
[flutter_shopify] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_shopify...                 
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-133.2.beta.



Because flutter_shopify requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because flutter_shopify requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

I changed the version to

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0-133.2.beta <3.0.0"
```

but this time, it said:

```
[flutter_shopify] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_shopify...                 
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-133.2.beta.



Because graphql 5.0.0-nullsafety.4 requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0 and no versions of graphql match >5.0.0-nullsafety.4 <6.0.0, graphql ^5.0.0-nullsafety.4 is forbidden.

So, because flutter_shopify depends on graphql ^5.0.0-nullsafety.4, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_shopify depends on graphql ^5.0.0-nullsafety.4, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

I'm too confused about it, I know that the version of Dart SDK following the flutter SDK, but it's now not satisfying to the dependences.

In this case, is there any way to upgrade my Dart SDK to higher than the version of flutter SDK holding?

This is `flutter doctor`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.2.0-10.2.pre, on macOS 11.3 20E232 darwin-x64, locale en-VN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0-10.2.pre at /.../flutter
    • Framework revision b5017bf8de (8 days ago), 2021-04-28 17:09:53 -0700
    • Engine revision 91ed51e05c
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-211.13.beta)
```

Please help! Thank you guys a lot!

Comment: I think the problem is cause you are using the beta channel, so dart version is > 2.12.0, the libraries are not compatible with 2.13.xxx yet.

Comment: You could change to stable channel to try.

Comment: change your sdk to `>=2.12.0 <3.0.0`. close the app. If possible uninstall the app and the restart it. It should work

Comment: @JorgeVieira Dart 2.13.0 > 2.12.0; that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of the Flutter or Dart SDKs installed?  Do you get the same error if you manually run `flutter pub get` in your project directory?  Somewhere you have Dart 2.12.0-133.2 installed.

Comment: @JorgeVieira I did change to `flutter channel stable` then `flutter upgrade`, the Dart version is still 2.12.0-133.2.beta. Don't know why.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes it's the same when I ran by command `flutter pub get`

Comment: @JorgeVieira, you are absolutely correct. I ran it on terminal and it worked

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem in the Visual Studio Code `settings.json`, where the `dart.flutterSdkPath` is setting incorrect to another folder.

Changing the `flutter channel stable` and `flutter upgrade` could resolve the problem with null-safety already.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I changed the sdk version to

> sdk: ">=3.0.6 <4.0.0"

and then update the run the pub get command.

Note: if you are using the ***feedback package*** in you project you should upgrade it to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I had copied a chunk of code from git. This was giving me this error. I created my app by running flutter create command, then copied the chunk of code in main.dart. The issue was with sdk version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).